# Using ios::in and ios::out simultaneously in fstream

Tags: c++11

When *fstream* is used only with `ios::out` *mode* for an already existing file, it truncates the file and writes the data into the opened file afresh (as expected).

But when *fstream* is used with both in and out modes as:

```
fstream fil;
fil.open("Student.dat",ios::out|ios::in);
```

it does not *truncate* the already existing file, rather it overwrites on to the file which results in a file containing the new contents with some of the already existing contents appended to the new contents, while the '`out`' mode is expected to truncate the already existing file.

*Can anybody please explain why that happens??*

Comment: Isn't the `ios::trunc` flag used for truncating?

Comment: The `ios::trunc` flag is used for truncating but it is available by default with `ios::out` and that can be seen when `ios::out` is used alone (i.e. without ios::in). So my ques is why is it no truncated by default when `ios::out` is used with ios::in.  Thanku for responding anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read from the file first you don't want it truncated first. It is left to your discretion. This is expected behaviour.